# How do I reshape a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I've loaded some messy data into Pandas and it's ended up as a long, one-row Dataframe.

I'd like to be able to reshape it so that every n-th column becomes a new row. Is there an efficient way of doing that?

(I think the main issue I have is I can't work out how to effectively code line separator ¬)

UPDATE:

To create something like the data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
zeroes = np.zeros(60000)
df = pd.DataFrame(zeroes)
df = df.T
df.head()
```

Comment: [MCVE] please...

Comment: I can't show the data.

Comment: We don't care about your data. We just want an example to reproduce the issue so we know what you're talking about. Make something up?

Comment: @coldspeed I've updated the question. I didn't mean to p off the community.

Comment: @IanS Updated. Didn't mean disrespect.

Comment: @IanS did not my solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only the non-standard line separator, please try:

```
pd.read_csv(..., lineterminator='¬')
```

Otherwise, would be helpful to see a sample of your data like @IanS suggested

Comment: If you ever have to request clarification in an answer ("But would be helpful to see a sample of your data"), you're better off not answering at all. Just FYI, since I see you posting here often.

Comment: @coldspeed Why? What's wrong with providing a limited answer to a limited question, which can later extend depending on additional question details?

Comment: @EliadL First of all, "limited questions" that do not provide [mcve]s or clear explanations or reproductions of any issues or code thereof shouldn't be answered in the first place (there's something better you can do—vote to close).

Comment: @coldspeed Again, why?

Comment: @EliadL because... that's how things work here...? If you have to ask why poor questions should be closed instead of answering, you should probably open a question on [meta].

Comment: @coldspeed And yet, this answer seems perfectly fine, despite not filling the criteria you've mentioned.

Comment: @EliadL I hope you are carefully reading my comments, because whatever I said applies to the question. It doesn't matter how good the answer is, if the question isn't well-asked, there's no point. I really see no point of further discussion.

Comment: @coldspeed Sorry, I meant that the *question* does not comply, and yet the answer is perfectly fine. I still don't see the problem here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189827/discussion-between-eliadl-and-coldspeed).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others you can easily solve this problem by parsing the data correctly (using read_csv). However, the below code should also work (which is inline with what you are looking for in the question). If *df* is your dataframe loaded as one single row.

```
n = 3
adf= pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,n))
```

Ofcourse `df.shape[1]%n == 0` i.e, the the number of values in the single row of df should be divisible by n so that reshape works.